# Computing the Integral of a Complicated Matrix Exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

For each $i = 1,2,\cdots,m$,
let $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be full rank,
and $v_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
Let us use the notation $[v_i]_{i=1}^m$ for the $m\times m$ matrix
created by stacking $v_i$ as column vectors.

Is it possible to compute the following integral in closed form?

$$ \int_0^t 
  \exp\left( 
  \left[ [A_i]^{-1} 
   ( \exp( -A_i s ) - I_m ) 
   v_i 
  \right]_{i=1}^m  
  \right) 
  \, ds \,. 
$$

If it helps, we know that the matrix $[v_i]_{i=1}^m$ is symmetric positive semidefinite,
and the tensor formed by $[A_i]_{i=1}^m = [a_{ijk}]_{i,j,k=1}^m$ is symmetric in the $i,j$ directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral likely does not have a closed form solution. In the scalar case (i.e. $m=1$), denoting $A_i = a$ and $v_i = v$, the integral can be computed (via Wolfram Alpha) as

$$ \int_0^t \exp( a^{-1}(e^{-at}-1)v ) = \frac{e^{-v/a}}{a} ( \text{Ei}(v/a) - \text{Ei}(e^{-at}v/a) ) \,, 
$$

where $\text{Ei}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x t^{-1}e^{t} dt$ is the exponential integral, which is not an elementary function.

Consequently, it's unlikely the higher dimension cases ($m > 1$) will admit a closed form solution.